Trying to create container app jobs with secret block and cronjob
I'm trying to deploy an Azure Container App Job using Terraform. The job should connect to a service Bus Namespace using a connection string, but i am encountering issues.
Below is the terraform code I'm working with:
data "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "iccm_servicebus" {
  for_each = var.iccm_primary_regions
  name                = "iccm-${var.environment}-service-bus-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name = "iccm_${var.environment}_shared_rg"
}
resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "caj-relay" {
  for_each = var.iccm_primary_regions
  name                         = "caj-relay-${var.environment}-${each.key}"
  location                     = each.key
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.relay[each.key].name
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.relay-container-app-environment[each.key].id
  secret {
    name = "servicebus-connection-string"
    value = data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.iccm_servicebus[each.value].default_primary_connection_string
  }
 
replica_timeout_in_seconds = 10
replica_retry_limit = 10
schedule_trigger_config {
  cron_expression = "* * * * *"
  parallelism = 4
  replica_completion_count = 1
}
 
template {
  container {
    image = "${var.container_registry_configuration.server}/outbox-message-relay-service:latest"
    name = "outbox-message-relay-service"
    readiness_probe {
      transport = "HTTP"
      port = 5000
    }
    liveness_probe {
      transport = "HTTP"
      port = 5000
      path = "/health"
      initial_delay = 5
      interval_seconds = 20
      timeout = 2
      failure_count_threshold = 1
    }
    startup_probe {
      transport = "TCP"
      port = 5000
    }
    cpu = 0.5
    memory = "1Gi"
  }
}
    env {
      name = "AzureServiceBus__ConnectionString"
      secret_name = "servicebus-connection-string"
     
    }
    env {
      name = "ApplicationInsights__ConnectionString"
      secret_name = "application-insights-connection-string"
     
    }
    env {
      name = "ConnectionStrings__CustDbConnection"
      secret_name = "customer-database-connection-string"
 
    }
 
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [
    template[0].container[0].name,
    template[0].container[0].image,
    template[0].container[0].env
   ]
}


Error message:

error:Block of type "****" are not expected here. Did you mean "***s"?

How can i pass the correct service Bus connection string to my container app?

Which version of the azurerm provider are you using? Check the official documentation to see which properties/blocks are supported or not.

3.104.2 @RuiJarimba

BTW shouldn't you be using each.key instead of each.value in the secret value? What is the value of var.iccm_primary_regions?

Yes I did try with each.key var .iccm_primary_region is east us

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Here is the updated code to create a container job with a reference to the Service Bus namespace secret.
varaibles.tf
variable "iccm_primary_regions" {
  description = "The primary Azure regions"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    eastus = "East US"
    westus = "West US"
  }
}

variable "resource_groups" {
  description = "Map of resource groups for each region"
  type        = map(object({
    name     = string
    location = string
  }))
  default = {
    "eastus" = {
      name     = "iccm1_dev_shared_rg_eastus"
      location = "East US"
    }
    "westus" = {
      name     = "iccm1_dev_shared_rg_westus"
      location = "West US"
    }
  }
}

variable "environment" {
  description = "The environment name"
  type        = string
  default = "dev"
}

terraform.tfvars
iccm_primary_regions = {
  "eastus"  = "East US"
  "westus"  = "West US"
}

ACR.tf
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "8332bf56-aa7c-4daa-a507-d7e60e5f09a9"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "iccm_resource_group" {
  for_each = var.iccm_primary_regions

  name     = "iccm1_dev_shared_rg_${each.key}"  
  location = each.value                          
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "iccm1_servicebus" {
  for_each = var.iccm_primary_regions
  name                = "iccm1-${var.environment}-service-bus-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name = "AKS_RG"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.iccm_resource_group ]
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "relay-container-app-environment" {
  for_each = var.iccm_primary_regions

  name                = "relay-environment-dev-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_groups[each.key].name  
  location            = var.resource_groups[each.key].location
depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.iccm_resource_group ]
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "caj-relay" {
  for_each = var.iccm_primary_regions
  name                         = "caj-relay-${var.environment}-${each.key}"
  location                     = each.key
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.iccm_resource_group[each.key].name
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.relay-container-app-environment[each.key].id

  secret {
    name  = "servicebus-connection-string"
    value = data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.iccm1_servicebus[each.key].default_primary_connection_string
  }
  replica_timeout_in_seconds = 10
  replica_retry_limit        = 10

  schedule_trigger_config {
    cron_expression           = "* * * * *"
    parallelism               = 4
    replica_completion_count  = 1
  }

  template {
    container {
      name   = "testcontainerappsjob0"
      image  = "nginx:latest"
      cpu    = 0.5
      memory = "1Gi"

      readiness_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 5000
      }

      liveness_probe {
        transport          = "HTTP"
        port               = 5000
        path               = "/health"
        initial_delay      = 5
        interval_seconds   = 20
        timeout            = 2
        failure_count_threshold = 1
      }

      startup_probe {
        transport = "TCP"
        port      = 5000
      }
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      template[0].container[0].name,
      template[0].container[0].image,
      template[0].container[0].env
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_container_app_environment.relay-container-app-environment ]
}




Terrafrom apply

After executing the script, the container job has been created with the Service Bus name space secret
caj-relay-dev-eastus

caj-relay-dev-westus

